# why isnt the jsp page compiled in Openshift Jboss as 7 with spring 4 mvc annotation

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jboss7.x, openshift

I have developed an java web application using maven and spring mvc 4 in eclipse. I am using spring annotation without web.xml and using jboss 7.1 application server.

I am using WebApplicationInitializer as i am not using web.xml

```
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
        throws ServletException {
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    webApplicationContext.register(Config.class);
    webApplicationContext.setServletContext(servletContext);

    Dynamic dispatcherServlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher",
            new DispatcherServlet(webApplicationContext));
    dispatcherServlet.addMapping("/*");
    dispatcherServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
```

My configuration code is shared below,

The jsp page is not rendered

```
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
    super.configureDefaultServletHandling(configurer);
};

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return viewResolver;
}
```

The output of the jsp page in the browser for the request is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```